# How to use typer.js in angular 6 components?

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend, angular6

I am using Angular 6, trying to put [typerjs](https://steven.codes/typerjs/) into angular.

I tried adding `typer.js` to `angular-cli.json`.

```
scripts: ["./assets/typer.js"],
```

Although I am able to successfully use it at the index.html but it is not working at the components when I move the demo html over.

I tried using [ng2-typerjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-typewriter) as well but it is not working as well I think it is outdated.